# Rank of day of a month without weekend days in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm looking for a DAX way to have a column in my table which corresponds to the DAY() function without weekend days. In France weekend days are Saturday and Sunday.

Like this:

```
Date|Month|Year|Rank of the day with weekend days|Rank of the day without weekend days

01/10/20201|10|2021|1|1

02/10/20201|10|2021|2|1

03/10/20201|10|2021|3|1

04/10/20201|10|2021|4|2

05/10/20201|10|2021|5|3
```

Answer (score 2):

With DAX Calculated column

You need to have following two columns in the dataset itself

```
| Date                          | Day#  | Week#     | Ranking   |
|----------------------------   |------ |-------    |---------  |
| Friday, October 1, 2021       | 6     | 40        | 1         |
| Saturday, October 2, 2021     | 7     | 40        | 1         |
| Sunday, October 3, 2021       | 1     | 41        | 1         |
| Monday, October 4, 2021       | 2     | 41        | 2         |
| Tuesday, October 5, 2021      | 3     | 41        | 3         |
| Wednesday, October 6, 2021    | 4     | 41        | 4         |
| Thursday, October 7, 2021     | 5     | 41        | 5         |
| Friday, October 8, 2021       | 6     | 41        | 1         |
| Saturday, October 9, 2021     | 7     | 41        | 1         |
| Sunday, October 10, 2021      | 1     | 42        | 1         |
| Monday, October 11, 2021      | 2     | 42        | 2         |
| Tuesday, October 12, 2021     | 3     | 42        | 3         |
```

such as

```
Day# =
WEEKDAY ( 'Table'[Date], 1 )

Week# =
WEEKNUM ( 'Table'[Date] )

Ranking =
VAR _week =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Week#] ) )
VAR _rank =
    RANKX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Week#] = _week
                && EARLIER ( 'Table'[Day#] ) <> 6
                && EARLIER ( 'Table'[Day#] ) <> 7
        ),
        'Table'[Date],
        ,
        ASC
    )
RETURN
    _rank
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your answer but it's not what i need. I need a similar DAX formula without counting each saturday and sunday of the month.

Comment: Added new solution

Comment: Hello smpa01,

We are close to the solution. But i need that my var _rank keep incrementing after the weekends and the var _rank need to be reset for each month.

Comment: Do you care to provide proper sample data and desired output clearly?